# How can i change each gameobject movement speed?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy i have 2 ThirdPersonController.
In the Window > Animator i created new empty state called it Walk and set it to HumanoidWalk so when running the game both players are walking.

On one of them i added the script and as Prefab the second ThirdPersonController(1).

Then when running the game it's making clones of the ThirdPersonController(1).
So i see in the Hierarchy more N ThirdPersoncontrollers.

Today to change the speed of walking for each ThirdPersonController i change in the Inspector the Move Speed Multiplier.
But if i want in the script already when creating the clones to set to each one another speed how can i do it ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Multiple_objects : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject[] gos;
    public int NumberOfObjects;

    void Awake()
    {
            gos = new GameObject[NumberOfObjects];
        for(int i = 0; i < gos.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            gos [i] = clone;

        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

What i tried now is to get the Animator component of the Prefab and set the speed to all the clones:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Multiple_objects : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject[] gos;
    public int NumberOfObjects;
    private Animator _animaotr;

    void Awake()
    {
            gos = new GameObject[NumberOfObjects];
        for(int i = 0; i < gos.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            gos [i] = clone;
            _animaotr.speed = 10;
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        _animaotr = prefab.GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

But the main problem is that on my first ThirdPersonController in the Hierarchy the original one i created in Window > Animator empty state called it Walk and set HumandoidWalk.

Now to set the speed for some reason changing the Animator speed never effect of anything for example:

```
_animaotr.speed = 10;
```

Only when changing the speed in the ThirdPersonController > Inspector > Third Person Character (Script) > Move Speed Multiplier. And it's changing the same speed to all ThirdPersoncontrollers in the Hierarchy including this i clone.

But how do i change each clone speed to another vlaue of speed ? And why the _animator.speed not changing anything and i need to use this Move Speed Multiplier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Move Speed Multiplier** property that is showing in the Editor is declared as `m_MoveSpeedMultiplier` in the `ThirdPersonCharacter` script. It is delacre as  `float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;` which means that it is a `private` variable and **cannot** be accessed from another script. The reason it is showing up in the Editor is because it has `[SerializeField]` on top of it which means that it is a serialized `private` variable.

*To access it during run-time, you have to change from `float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;` to `public float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;` in the `ThirdPersonCharacter` script.*

Use `GetComponent` to get instance of `ThirdPersonCharacter` from the gos GameObject then save it somewhere for re-usual. Since you have 2 `ThirdPersonCharacter`, you can create two `ThirdPersonCharacter` arrays to hold those instances. It should look like the code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class Multiple_objects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject[] gos;
    public int NumberOfObjects;

    private ThirdPersonCharacter[] thirdPersonCharacter;

    void Awake()
    {
        thirdPersonCharacter = new ThirdPersonCharacter[2];

        gos = new GameObject[NumberOfObjects];
        for (int i = 0; i < gos.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            gos[i] = clone;
            thirdPersonCharacter[i] = clone.GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        thirdPersonCharacter[0].m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 5f;
        thirdPersonCharacter[1].m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The property m_MoveSpeedMultiplier not exist.

Comment: @TheLostLostit Please read the instruction again. **"to access it during run-time, you have to change from `float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;` to `public float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;` in the `ThirdPersonCharacter` script."**